# androidアプリでGoogleFit連携時に未確認アプリの警告がでます

Tags: android, firebase, oauth

GoogleFit連携機能を持つアプリをアップデートリリースするにあたり、Google Play Store で内部テスト配信、またはクローズドテスト配信（以降、テスト配信）でアプリのGoogleFit連携機能を確認すると、「 このアプリはGoogleで確認されていません 」の警告が表示され、この原因がわからず困っています。
（申請が通り、本番の公開準備が完了していても同様になっています。）
どなたか、アドバイスいただきたいです。

参考: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865#unverified-app-screen

[image: 表示されるダイアログ]

### 詳細

- 前提としてReact-nativeで作成されたアプリです
- すでにリリース済みのバージョンのテスト配信のバイナリではこの事象は起きない
- すでにリリース済みのバイナリとアップデート用のテスト配信したバイナリのGoogleによる署名は一致している
- アップデートバイナリではtargetSdkVersionを29から31にアップデートしており、その都合、必要なライブラリのアップデートのために google-services.json を持つように変更されている

  - google-services.json は firebase console で今回のアップデートのために作成したプロジェクトからDLしたもので、作成時は既存の Google Cloud Console に登録済みのプロジェクトを連携して作成されたものです。
  - Google Cloud Console でAPI設定されている FitnessAPI は有効になっている

    - FitnessAPIで登録されている認証情報のOAuthクライアントIDに設定されている署名はPlayStoreで登録しているバイナリの署名と一致しており、変更はしていない
    - FitnessAPIで登録されている認証情報のOAuthクライアントIDに設定されているパッケージはPlayStoreで登録しているバイナリのパッケージと一致しており、変更していない
    - FitnessAPIで登録されている認証情報のOAuthクライアントIDに、google-services.json 追加したことによってか、「Web client (auto created by Google Service)」が追加で登録されている
    - FitnessAPIで登録されている認証情報のAPIキーは、google-services.json 追加したことによってか、「Android key (auto created by Firebase)」「Browser key (auto created by Firebase)」の2つが追加されている。設定は両方ともデフォルトのまま。
    - FitnessAPIで登録されている認証情報の、OAuthクライアントIDに設定されている署名は google-services.json に登録している（FirebaseConsoleからフィンガープリント追加で設定している）
    - FitnessAPI設定のOAuth同意画面設定は既存のバージョンリリース時に、Googleによる検査済みで本番環境となっおり、設定は変更していない（もちろんスコープも変更していない）
- アプリからFitにアクセスするときのコードは変更していない。

### google-fit関連コード

project/build.gradle の buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.3"
        excludeAppGlideModule = true
        kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
        androidXCore = "1.6.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

project/app/build.gradle の dependencies 抜粋

```
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-fit"), {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: 'play-services-auth'
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: 'play-services-fitness'
    })
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:21.1.0"
```

Comment: 解決しました。
targetSdkVersion 31 にしたことによって react-native-google-fit ライブラリもバージョン変更する必要があり、それによって、デフォルトでリクエストするFitnessAPIのスコープがOAuth認証同意設定に設定されているものと差分がありました。
アプリの方でスコープを修正することで解決しました。